# Which chmod should I use for a production environment when configuring MongoDB in /data/db?

Tags: macos, bash, mongodb, production-environment, chmod

I am installing MongoDB for the first time. These are the steps I have taken:

```
tar xvf mongodbosx-x86_64-2.6.4.tgz
cd mongodbosx-x86_64-2.6.4.tgz
cd bin
sudo bash
mkdir -p /data/db
chmod 777 /data/db
```

I believe I should use another number but not sure which specifically works best. I want to create a MEAN application for product inventory.

Comment: What is the error you are getting? What is the expected outcome?

Comment: If your concern here is about security, you're going to need someone on your team/project who understands security.  Changing 777 to some other number is not going to make your system secure.  If you don't care about security, try just not chmod'ing at all, or sure, use 777 which will make your database writable by any logged in user on your system.

Comment: I strongly advice against following @JohnZwinck's advice: while it works, it is ***bad*** practise, grants unnecessary permissions and tends to be reused on machines where it _does_ make a difference (shared environments of any kind). Since you will be running _all_ processes under your effective user ID (euid), doing a `chmod 0755 /data/db` is sufficient and best practise, as it gives mongoDB _sufficient_ rights to access the directory and prevents every process not started with your euid from writing to it.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg: to be clear, my advice was not to do 777 except as a last resort if one simply does not care at all about security.

Comment: I understand, I will chmod 0755, Thanks for all the help!